# Macro for Loop through outlook unread emails

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying adapt this code for use the macro only in unread emails in my Inbox, but I don’t get anything that works. Someone for helping me? THanks in advance.

```
Public Sub Unread_eMails()

Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace

Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder

Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder


Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("CHECK")


'For Each MyItem In myInbox

 
For Each MyItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.**¿?** 'I don't know what type here... 



If myInbox.UnReadItemCount <> 0 Then


     If InStr(MyItem.Body, "alarm") > 0 Then

        MyItem.Move myDestFolder

     Else

     If InStr(MyItem.Subject, "Urgent") > 0 Then

        MyItem.Move myDestFolder

     Else


     If InStr(MyItem.Body, "Closed") > 0 Then

        MyItem.Categories = "Closed"

        MyItem.Save

    End If

    End If

    End If

   
    MyItem.UnRead = False 
End If

Next MyItem        

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use the object browser to determine what methods/objects are available. View.ObjectBrowser then select Outlook as your library and browse from there.

Comment: Thans @freeflow Is there any example where I can learn to do what you suggest? First days with VBA Outlook and I still learning. If I put in google View.ObjectBrowser and Unred eMails I don't get results. Thank you!

Comment: In the VBA IDE  use the menu Iterm Tools

Comment: @freeflow Menu>Tools>References? I don't undertand man... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Aaagh.  Apologies.  View.Object Browser

Comment: I really did it... But I have the same problem. I don't find the solution for unread emails... F2 for View.Object Browser, then Outlook and I have the same options that before... 

Outlook Application.ActiveExplorer. ¿?

Outlook Application.ActiveWindow... ¿?

I can't find the option for Unread emails

Comment: Seems like your google fu is pretty weak.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.UnRead

Comment: What are trying to do with the unread emails?

Comment: Take a look at the live Outlook objects with OutlookSpy - http://www.dimastr.com/outspy

Answer (score 0):

Limit the items to those that are unread with `Restrict`.

Loop in reverse when moving or deleting.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Public Sub Unread_eMails()

Dim myInbox As folder
Dim myDestFolder As folder

Dim myItem As Object

Dim myItems As Items
Dim myRestrictedItems As Items

Dim i As Long

Set myInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("CHECK")

If myInbox.UnReadItemCount <> 0 Then

    Set myItems = myInbox.Items

    ' Restrict to unread items
    Set myRestrictedItems = myItems.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
    
    ' Reverse loop when moving or deleting
    For i = myRestrictedItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        
        Set myItem = myRestrictedItems(i)
        
        ' Note: InStr is case sensitive
        If InStr(myItem.body, "alarm") > 0 Then
            myItem.Move myDestFolder
        
        ElseIf InStr(myItem.subject, "Urgent") > 0 Then
            myItem.Move myDestFolder
        
        ElseIf InStr(myItem.body, "Closed") > 0 Then
            myItem.categories = "Closed"    ' save required
            myItem.Save
            
            myItem.UnRead = False           ' save not required
            
        End If
    
    Next

End If

End Sub
```